# Using lambda functions in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to match links that contain certain texts. I'm doing

```
links = soup.find_all('a',href=lambda x: ".org" in x)
```

But that throws a TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

The correct way of doing it is apparantly

```
links = soup.find_all('a',href=lambda x: x and ".org" in x)
```

Why is the additional `x and` necessary here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a simple reason: One of the `<a>` tags in your HTML has no `href` property.

---

Here's a minimal example that reproduces the exception:

```
html = '<html><body><a>bar</a></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: ".org" in x)
# result:
# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Now if we add a `href` property, the exception disappears:

```
html = '<html><body><a href="foo.org">bar</a></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: ".org" in x)
# result:
# [<a href="foo.org">bar</a>]
```

What's happening is that BeautifulSoup is trying to access the `<a>` tag's `href` property, and that returns `None` when the property doesn't exist:

```
html = '<html><body><a>bar</a></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.a.get('href'))
# output: None
```

This is why it's necessary to allow `None` values in your lambda. Since `None` is a falsy value, the code `x and ...` prevents the right side of the `and` statement from being executed when `x` is `None`, as you can see here:

```
>>> None and 1/0
>>> 'foo.org' and 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

This is called [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

---

That said, `x and ...` checks the truthiness of `x`, and `None` is not the only value that's considered falsy. So it would be more correct to compare `x` to `None` like so:

```
lambda x: x is not None and ".org" in x
```

Comment: why `x and ".org" in x`, this is a problem which I have searched for a long time, `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` also is a error which is getting me in trouble now; both of us are in your answer

Answer (score 0):

The additional `x` avoids the problem that you had, i.e `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType'`. Try calling the lambda function with `None` as the argument:

```
>>> f = lambda x: ".org" in x
>>> f
<function <lambda> at 0x7f5dd1215ea0>
>>> f(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
>>> f('abcd.org/blah')
True
```

The first `x` in `x and ".org" in x` tests whether `x` is "truthy". If it is the rest of the expression is evaluated. If it is not "truthy", e.g. it is None, then the second part of the `and` expression is short circuited and not executed. This avoids attempting to perform the `in` operation, thereby avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an `<a ...>` tag may have no `href=...` part and in this case you get a `None` (that cannot be used with the `in` operator).